# Trying to Loop Through functions. coroutine never awaited on 2nd loop

Tags: python, async-await, telethon

I'm pretty new to programming, but I've been working on this code and finally getting somewhere. I'm using telethon api to scan a TG group and then do something with the code.

My program has a main screen, where I take input then loop through functions before getting back to the main screen.

The first run works perfectly, but then when it gets back to main screen 2 things happen.

1. I get coroutine was never awaited.

```
    RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UpdateMethods._run_until_disconnected' was 
    never awaited
        client.run_until_disconnected()
    RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AuthMethods._start' was never awaited
      client.start()
```

2. It starts running the functions after it without another event happening

The actual code has more functions that actually do things besides print, but I left out those and just replaced with print to give an idea of what they're doing since those are working.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I apologize in advance if my code is very messy!

```
client = TelegramClient('anon', config['telegram_id'], config['telegram_hash'])

def mainScreen():
     # Display Wallet / Buy Info
    print('Wallets List')
    print('------------')

    for address in addresses:
        print(address["wallet"] + ' | Amount to buy: ' 
        + str(address["amount"]) + ' | Current Balance : ' 
        + str(web3.fromWei(web3.eth.get_balance(address["wallet"]), 'ether')))
    # Print Options
    print('')
    print('What do you want to do?')
    print('-----------------------')
    print('')
    print('1) TG Scan')
    print('')

    input("Enter your answer: ")
    scanTg1()
    # Take input 

def scanTg1():
    print('')
    if config['tgGroup'] == "":
        group = input("Link to the TG: ")
    else: 
        group = config['tgGroup']
    print("Scanning : " + group)
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=group))
    async def my_event_handler(event):
        global handleNewMessage
        if event.raw_text is not None and handleNewMessage == True:
            if 'stealth' in event.raw_text.lower():
                if '0x' in event.raw_text:
                    x = event.raw_text.split()
                    for string in x:
                        if '0x' in string:
                            start = string.index('0')
                            contract = Web3.toChecksumAddress(string[start:start+42].lower())
                            contractFound = await checkContract(contract)
                            if contractFound == True:
                                print("Contract Found: " + contract)
                                handleNewMessage = False
                                await buyTheToken(contract)
                    if contractFound == False:
                        if 't.me' in event.raw_text:
                            x = event.raw_text.split()
                            for string in x:
                                if 't.me' in string:
                                    tgLink =x[x.index(string)] 
                                    print("Found " + tgLink)
                                    await scanOldMessages(tgLink)
                        else:
                            print('*')
                

                elif 't.me' in event.raw_text:
                    x = event.raw_text.split()
                    for string in x:
                        if 't.me' in string:
                            tgLink =x[x.index(string)] 
                            print("Found " + tgLink)
                            await scanOldMessages(tgLink)
                else:
                    print('*')        
            else:
                print('*')
    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()

async def buyTheToken(contract):
    print("Bought the Token")
    sellToken()

def sellToken():
    print("Token sold")
    mainScreen()
```

Comment: await client.start(), and you need use async def

Comment: When I do this, it never starts scanning the TG group

Comment: you're trying to run a coro without awaiting it.  you also have what looks like a factory fn: avoid defining fns inside fns unless you *need* to do so (you don't here).  Thus you either need to `await client.start()` and then actually *run* the event loop: `asyncio.run_until_complete(client.run_until_disconnected())`.  Currently you don't have an event loop at all.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I moved it out of the other function. When I try to do what you said the api just doesn't scan anything. Any idea how I can fix? Only way it runs is if I don't await it. But then the 2nd run it doesn't